# Coredata fetch-request with a sequence order

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm using core data and fetching the results based on an array of ids. This array of ids is the sequence I needed to fetch. But the fetched results are not in that order. What should I do in order to fetch the objects exactly match with the order of the array of ids?

```
// get manageObjectContext
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SomeName"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K IN %@", @"anId", arr];

NSError *error;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
fetchRequest = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

As best I can find, Core Data does not support this.  That leaves you with the option of either retrieving the objects one at a time, or sorting after you retrieve them.  My hunch is that for relatively small sets, sorting in memory after retrieving them is faster, but that probably depends on lots of variables, like the architecture of the underlying database, how things are indexed, etc.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = NSSortDescriptor(key: "anId", ascending: true or false)
```

Comment: Its not in ascending order, sequence is different

Comment: .sort({ $0.property > $1.property}) if you want a specific sequence  what is it ?